# LinqToSql calling default method

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a database with a table called Articles.

The Table stores Articles and has a field CDTimeStamp.
The CDTimestamp field got altered like this, so that it always has the correct creation date:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Artikel] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Artikel_CDTimeStamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CDTimeStamp]
GO
```

So if I try to add an article, I get an error.
The article is added like this:

```
public void AddArticle()
{
    this.Open();

    Article article = new Article();
    article.Description = "";
    article.ArticleNr = GetArticleNumber();
    article.Barcode = GetBarcode(); //EAN
    article.Branch = GetBranch(); // 3digit number
    article.Company = GetCompany(); // 1 or 2
    article.Preis = GetPrice();
    article.PreisNew = GetNewPrice();
    //article.CDTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

    _OutDataContext.Artikel.InsertOnSubmit(article);
    try
    {
        this.Submit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

The error I get is:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

If I uncomment `//article.CDTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;` a DateTime is created and inserted but the getdate() default value should be inserted and not the value I create in my program.
My question is:
Is there a configuration entry or something alike that enables the calling of the default function ? The database field may not be null.

**P.S.**
I wasn't quite sure how to call this question so please feel free to edit it if you know a more correct title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ColumnAttribute.IsDbGenerated` is what you are looking for.
In class mapping use something like:

```
class Article 
{
    [Column(..., IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public DateTime CDTimeStamp { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: Very simple answer thank you. FYI In the dbml explorer I could set a Property which is called "Auto Generated Value" which then produces the IsDbGenerated attribute.